# Gulpfile Javascript Concat Issue

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp

I am trying to get my gulp file working right and I am not sure whats wrong. Here is the file. https://gist.github.com/digilord/9265640 The section I am having issues with is the js:dev. When a coffeescript file is changed it drops the resulting js file into the app/js directory. The js:dev rule isn't picking up that change. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediate solution: gulp-watch needs the glob information to find new files. You can pass your glob to its [glob option](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch#optionsglob). Something like:

```
return gulp.src('app/js/*.coffee')
      .pipe(watch({glob: 'app/js/*.coffee'}))
```

Meanwhile if you were to use `gulp.watch()` it wouldn't pick up new files either but only because of a bug in its dependency, which a fix is coming soon for.

I have to also mention that your gulpfile is needlessly complex. Your coffee and js operations could be in the same stream instead of creating intermediate js files. I also don't really know why some of your streams are repeated twice. Stay dry:

```
var coffeeGlob = 'app/js/*.coffee';

gulp.task('js:dev', ['clean:dev'], function() {
    return gulp.src(coffeeGlob)
      .pipe(watch({glob: coffeeGlob}))
      .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gutil.log))
      .pipe(concat('app.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
      .pipe(reload());
});
```

As I mentioned on IRC the boilerplate you based it on might not be up to date with best practices, and I recommend basing on something newer like [Yeoman's gulp generator's gulpfile](http://yeoman.io/blog/gulp-explore.html).